# allow assignment of barewords to single variable while still using strict in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to continue to use strict, but there is one specific location where I want to assign a bareword to a variable, for use as a hash key later.  I'm looking for a way to allow this cleanly while still allowing me to use strict.

A simplified version of my code would be something like this:

```
sub assignElement{
   my $self = shift;
   my($element_name, $value) = @_;

   #sanity check values

   $self->{$element_name} = $value;
}

sub assignName{
 my $self = shift;
 my($value) = @_;

 $self->assignElement(name, $value);
}

sub assignAddress{
 my $self = shift;
 my($value) = @_;

 $self->assignElement(addr, $value);
}
```

The real code is more complex, but effectively I'm doing something like the above, using a generic assignElement method which works for various element values to allow code reuse.

The element keys are predefined and are currently all bareword.  I know I could make them strings, but I sort of prefer them to stay barewords.  They are referenced quite often and it's tedious to quote them ever time; and besides I use barewords in every other hashkey so it would feel inconsistent to not use barewords in this case.

Is there a way I can tell perl to ignore the strict check on barewords for the single method call (or a single variable assignment) while allowing use strict to function otherwise as usual?

Comment: A strange request. Could `assignElement(name => $value)` work? Or could you just make them constants (which would help avoid spelling errors)? Or subs (`sub name { 'name' }`)?

Comment: @toolic psh, functional code is so overrated ;)  updated it, and will be more careful when copying and pasting :)

Comment: @Biffen I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what your asking.  The line as you wrote it doesn't work, it appears not to be grammatically correct.  I think what your suggesting though is to pass in an anonymous hash.  Yes your right that would work, but wouldn't be that pretty.  Since I'm appending to an existing hash I would have to pass in an anonymous hash, use Keys to find and pull the key and value out of the passed hash, and then use those to insert into the final hash (plus I need key and value for error checking).  So that would work, but hoping a cleaner options exists :)

Comment: @Biffen oh go and update your comment as I'm replying, I see how it is.  Yes constants may be a good option if they can be barewords,  let me look into defining constants to see how that works lol.  such a perl newb right now...

Comment: The line works fine as long as `assignElement` knows what to do with it. If you're looking for a *clean* solution, don't use barewords (IMHO).

Comment: @Biffen it doesn't appear I can declare barewords as constants.  I think I'd rather remove barewords then do the hash work around.  I just recall there being a syntax to allow things like ignoring function prototype so wanted to see if a comparable way to say "allow me to break the rules for one line" existed before I gave up and tossed barewords entirely.

Comment: `sub assignElement($element_name, $value){` is a syntax error in Perl. Perhaps you are thinking of some other language.

Comment: Also, I do not see the reason you think you have to use a bareword, as using a string `foo("name", $value)` works perfectly well. There is a reason the `strict` pragma is strict -- it is because it is good practice, and it helps you avoid mistakes that can be hard to detect. In short, this is a horrible idea.

Comment: Consider this, for example: `perl -MData::Dumper -lwe"sub a { my ($x,$y) = @_; $foo{$x} = $y; }; a(time, 12); print Dumper \%foo;`

Comment: @ikegami yes you are correct.  I'm not use to thinking perl, it seems when I write fast psudocode I fall back to the language I'm more use to.  I have corrected the example.

Comment: @TLP only reason for barewords is due to the frequency of using the variables, it's a little more convenient to not have to quote each key; and to stay consistent to other bareword key's used in other hashes in our code.  In other words, no nothing ties me to it too strongly; if no clean option exists to do what I want I will remove barewords.  I just wanted to check if there *was* a clean solution before falling back to removal of the barewords.

Comment: @dsollen You should never use pseudocode. It will confuse the issue, as there may be subtle mistakes, and your code might be say something different than what you are saying. Never include code that you have not run yourself and know the result of.

Comment: @TLP Not necessarily a syntax error: Signatures have been around since v5.20.

Comment: @dsollen Generally speaking, if you have a "hidden" assumption like that, one day it is going to come back and bite you in the butt. There is a reason good practice is good: It does good things. I would say the "cleanest" you're going to get is using the fat arrow `=>` syntax, but the best is to just suck it up and use quotes. Using quotes will make your code more solid, more readable and less prone to subtle bugs. You are literally thinking of sacrificing hours in possible debug time to gain milliseconds in pressing two extra keys.

Comment: @TLP I understand what your saying, but I doubt anyone wants to parse through a 3-4 level deep hash map with predefined format and the logic for pulling out child values for modification.  I was at fault for not writing proper perl, my instincts still aren't 'perl' enough it seems, but I think simplified code is better then cluttered confusion for such a simple question as this in general, if someone isn't too incompetent to write basic perl.  And yes, I think I'm using quotes, having seen the alternatives.  I still appreciate learning what the alternatives were though.

Comment: @dsollen The option to posting pseudocode that you have not run is not to post the code you are actually using, but to post code that demonstrates the problem you are facing. In other words: Run the code before you post it to make sure it is what you say it is.

Comment: The (fractions of a second) you save by omitting the quotes will be lost many times over by the person who has to debug your program when you call `assignElement(foo, $value)` and there's a subroutine named `foo` somewhere else in the code. `strict 'subs'` exists for a very good reason.

Answer (score 5):

With a minor change:

```
$self->assignElement(name => $value);
$self->assignElement(addr => $value);
```

Downsides:

- The corresponding getter would be ugly (`$self->getElement(name =>)`) or inconsistent (`$self->getElement('name')`).

---

Without change: (Creates constants/subs named `addr` and `name`)

```
use constant {
   map {; $_ => $_ } qw(
      addr name
   )
};

$self->assignElement(name, $value);
$self->assignElement(addr, $value);
```

Downsides:

- You'd have to define/import the constants in all the modules that want to use them.
- Conflicts are likely.

Comment: I did try the constants option, it didn't work as well as I had hoped.  The problem is that when I use a constant in a hash key it's treated as a bareword, so now I need to append a & in front of the constant when I use it as a key directly.  Ultimately if these are my only options I think I'll simply remove barewords as the cleanest approach.  Still, you did answer my question for how it would be done; it just proves to be too much of a hassle to justify keeping barewords in first place.  Will likely select this as answer if no new brilliant option is posted in next hour.  Thank you.

Comment: `+` would be better than `&` (for performance reasons). /// Technically, no, you don't need to add the `&` (or `+`) if the name and value of the constant are the same as in my answer. There are, however, some other serious problems using that method, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Why do I not need to use & and how does the name matter?  if I could do constants without the &/+ it would be the cleanest option (this is all in one object so not worried about importing them elsewhere).  I just didn't think there is a way to avoid the +.  Can you help me understand why it isn't needed if I do something like $self->{name}?  I'm stuck with a rather old perl version (5.10.1) so maybe your referencing feature I can't use?

Comment: `$self->{name}` is the same with and without `use constant name => 'name';`. You don't have to use `$self->{&name}`. I'm not sure what's the confusion.

Comment: would not $self{name}= 'foo'; assign foo to the bareword name, rather then the treating name as a constant and using the 'name' value, which is different from $self{'name'} = 'foo'?  so if I call $self->assignElements(name, $value) I would end up doing a call of $self->{'name'}=$value in assignElement because the constant name is converted to 'name'.  Then if I later have a getter method with return $self->{name} I would look for the bareword key name, instead of identifying it as a constant, which doesn't exist and return undefined rather then returning the value saved in $self->{'name'}?

Comment: Do you think there's some difference between `$self->{name}` and `$self->{"name"}`. There isn't. It doesn't matter how the string is obtained. They both lookup the key named `name`.

Comment: I think @dsollen is asking why `perl -Mconstant=foo,bar -E'$h{foo} = "baz"; say keys %h'` prints `foo` instead of `bar`. And the reason is explained in the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#CAVEATS) for `constant`: "You can get into trouble if you use constants in a context which automatically quotes barewords (as is true for any subroutine call). For example, you can't say `$hash{CONSTANT}` because `CONSTANT` will be interpreted as a string. Use `$hash{CONSTANT()}` or `$hash{+CONSTANT}` to prevent the bareword quoting mechanism from kicking in."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I don't think so. He consistently used `name` throughout his comment. But if so, I specifically said "if the name and value of the constant are the same"